# Splitting Atom categories into two fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds

I am using [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import an [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) feed into my site.  The feed has categories as

```
<category term="cat:Foo" scheme="http://www.sixapart.com/ns/types#category" />
<category term="tag:foo" label="foo" scheme="http://www.sixapart.com/ns/types#tag" />
```

I would like to split the categories to one taxonomy, and the tags to another.  I have been playing with the [Feeds Tamper](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) for a while, but I cannot get any of the existing tampers to do what I want.

Mapping one Atom element to two fields is easy.  The problem is to exclude certain terms from being created.

From the [plugin list](https://drupal.org/node/1246578), the filters work on the item level and not the value level.

Is the only option to [make my own plugin](https://drupal.org/node/1246602)?

Comment: Sounds like you need the CERN module...

Comment: This has been unanswered for so long it's bugging me, I'll tell you how I'd do it, mostly because I wouldn't want to get in to having to learn about the Feeds/Tamper modules: [Create a menu callback function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), have this function [parse your Atom](http://simplepie.org/) feeds based on the argument passed in the callback. Then, create two feed imports, using your callback URL with the arguments to switch categories.